# Probability Question: 52 Card Deck Probability of Drawing A Certain Hand

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Connor randomly draws five cards from a 52-card deck.  Calculate the probability for each given event.

Connor has four-of-a-kind

So I had an earlier problem that asked about four kings specifically, and I set that one up correctly, but I'm not sure how to set it up if it can be four of any card?

Comment: multiply by 13.  i.e it equals 4 aces + 4 king + 4 queens + ... 4 twos.

Comment: What do you mean by "four of a kind"? Do you mean four of the same suit, or four of the same rank? Or perhaps four of the same color?

Comment: 4 if the same card like four kings or four nines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

P(Conner has 4 of a kind) is given by

$$ \frac{\binom{13}{1} \binom{12}{1} \binom{4}{4}}{\binom{52}{5}} $$

Reasoning:

$$ \binom{13}{1} $$

is the number of ways you can select a card number (A through K)

$$ \binom{12}{1} $$

is the number of ways you can select the remaining card (you are choosing 5 cards total)

$$ \binom{4}{4} $$

is the number of ways to choose the suit for the remaining card

$$ \binom{52}{5} $$

is the total number of 5-card hands you can create.

Answer (score 0):

There are $13$ ways to select a face for the quadruple, and $12\times 4$ ways to select a card (face and suit) for the singleton.

$$\dfrac{13\cdot 12\cdot 4}{^{52}\mathrm C_{5}}$$

Which should be $13$ times the answer for selecting four kings and a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{13\times 48}{\binom{52}{5}}
$$

$13$ ways to choose the rank of the "four-of-a-kind", and then choose any fifth card from the remaining $48$ cards.